# Convert a list to vector/df while maintaining dimension despite character(0) elements

Tags: r

I have a list that looks like this:

```
> dput(res[1:10])
list(character(0), c("Luzhuang", "Laisu", "Peihui"), character(0), 
    c("Anjiangping", "Xinzhai", "Yongfeng"), character(0), character(0), 
    c("Puji", "Gaotun", "Banjingcun"), character(0), character(0), 
    character(0))
```

In this example the list is of length 10. I want to get back a vector or data.frame that's also 10 elements long.

Most of the ways I've tried doing this omit the elements with `character(0)` or have other problems. My most recent attempt was:

```
library(plyr)
geo <- rbind.fill(lapply(res, function(f) {
  as.data.frame(Filter(Negate(is.null), f))
}))
```

My expected output would be:

```
character(0)
Luzhuang Laisu Peihui
character(0) 
Anjiangping Xinzhai Yongfeng
character(0)
character(0)
Puji Gaotun Banjingcun
character(0)
character(0) 
character(0)
```

or something similar. I don't care if the blank rows say `character(0)` or `NA` or nothing at all. The reason is that the list was created based on a dataframe that has the same length (by which I mean the nrows of the data.frame = the length of the list) and now I want to add the values in the list back to the data.frame.

If it's easier, you could do an example that has 1 word per non-empty element.

Comment: What is your expected output? You only have 9 non-empty elements.

Comment: @r2evans I added my expected output, thanks. 10 is the total number of elements (not just non-empty). I want the output to be the same length as the input list and basically to look exactly like it.

Comment: I don't think you can have `character(0)` as an element of a vector or data.frame. Can you accept `NA`? (I've never seen `NULL` in a data.frame.)

Comment: @r2evans Yes sure, that's fine. I just need it to be comfortable with a data frame that's the same length (in terms of number of rows) as the list's length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this suffice?

```
res <- list(character(0), c("Luzhuang", "Laisu", "Peihui"), character(0), 
    c("Anjiangping", "Xinzhai", "Yongfeng"), character(0), character(0), 
    c("Puji", "Gaotun", "Banjingcun"), character(0), character(0), 
    character(0))
res <- sapply(res, function(s) if (length(s) == 0) NA_character_ else paste(s, collapse = " "))
res
#  [1] NA                             "Luzhuang Laisu Peihui"       
#  [3] NA                             "Anjiangping Xinzhai Yongfeng"
#  [5] NA                             NA                            
#  [7] "Puji Gaotun Banjingcun"       NA                            
#  [9] NA                             NA
```

From here, putting it in a data.frame is straight-forward.

Comment: That's beautiful. I've never even seen `NA_character_` before.

Comment: I was actually just thinking to myself that there's got to be a more elegant method, but thanks :-)

Comment: Squashing it up - `sapply(replace(res, lengths(res)==0, NA), paste, collapse=" ")`

Comment: The only reason for the more verbose `NA_character_` is my tendency to try to be type-intentional. There are other forms of `NA` and they all are relatively compatible, so if this were codegolf I would of course remove that. @thelatemail Nice, I have no idea what `replace` is not in my toolkit, thanks!